# NetFlow configuration on Catalyst 4500-X

Tags: cisco-catalyst, netflow

I have a problem with config NetFlow on 4500-X switch.

This is NetFlow config

```
flow record NFArecord
 match ipv4 tos
 match ipv4 protocol
 match ipv4 source address
 match ipv4 destination address
 match transport source-port
 match transport destination-port
 match interface input netflow
 match interface output netflow
 collect counter bytes
 collect counter packets
 collect timestamp sys-uptime first
 collect timestamp sys-uptime last
!
!
flow exporter ELK
 destination 172.17.214.33
 transport udp 9966
!
!
flow monitor NFAmonitor
 exporter ELK
 cache timeout inactive 30
 cache entries 10000
 record NFArecord
!
```

I want to collect records for inter vlan traffic.

Try to do this:

```
interface Port-channel2 
//this is port-channel to SW3750, want to collect ingress traffic on in interface
 description Trunk to 6floor
 switchport
 switchport mode trunk
 end

Core-4500x(config-if)#ip flow monitor NFAmonitor in
% Flow Monitor: Flow Monitor 'NFAmonitor' - Incompatible traffic type: Record has Undetermined, monitor applied with IPv4
```

Ok, try to apply ip flow to vlan 60 and have same result:

```
Core-4500x(config-vlan-config)#ip flow monitor NFAmonitor input 
% Flow Monitor: Flow Monitor 'NFAmonitor' - Incompatible traffic type: Record has Undetermined, monitor applied with IPv4

Core-4500x(config-vlan-config)#ip flow monitor NFAmonitor layer2-switched input 
% Flow Monitor: Flow Monitor 'NFAmonitor' - Incompatible traffic type: Record has Undetermined, monitor applied with IPv4
```

What's wrong? What should I do for NetFlow working?

Comment: I have zero experience with netflow on Cisco, but my guess would be that you're trying to apply *ip* settings on a *switched* (layer 2) interface, which just doesn't make much sense. You apply netflow on routed interfaces.

Comment: @TeunVink's answer is correct. And if you use "datalink flow monitor" command, it can be applied to Layer 2 port.

Answer (score 1):

From your error it seems that some of flow records cannot be used for Layer-3 flow capture.

Try this configuration. It will be applied on bridge level.

```
flow record FLOW-RECORD-IPV4
 match ipv4 protocol
 match ipv4 source address
 match ipv4 destination address
 match transport source-port
 match transport destination-port
 match interface input
 collect interface output
 collect counter bytes long
 collect counter packets long

flow exporter FLOW-EXPORTER-X.X.X.X
 description FLOW-EXPORTER X.X.X.X
 destination X.X.X.X
 source VlanX
 transport udp 2055

flow monitor FLOW-MONITOR-IN
 description MONITOR INGRESS FLOWS
 record FLOW-RECORD-IPV4
 exporter FLOW-EXPORTER-X.X.X.X
 cache timeout inactive 60

vlan configuration 10,20,30,40,50,60
ip flow monitor FLOW-MONITOR-IN input
```

Also you could apply it on interface level:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/3/1
 ip flow monitor FLOW-MONITOR-IN input
```